# Kendo MVC Ajax Grid : Values are not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

net mvc4 project with Kendo UI iam using a simple ajax grid to print values from the database but it is not showing on the grid my code is

```
<%: Html.Kendo().Grid<CustomerTest.Models.ProductViewModel>()
   .Name("grid")
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .Read(read => read
                   .Action("Printc", "Home") // Set the action method which will return the data in JSON format
              // .Data("productsReadData") // Specify the JavaScript function which will return the data
          )
      )
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(product => product.CustomerID);
          columns.Bound(product => product.CustomerFName);
          columns.Bound(product => product.CustomerLName);
      })
      .Pageable()
      .Sortable()
%>
```

and my action method is

```
 public ActionResult Printc()
    {
       // ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View(GetCustomers());
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> GetCustomers()
    {
        var northwind = new CustomerLinqDataContext();
        var purchCount = northwind.Customer_details.Count();
        return northwind.Customer_details.Select(product => new ProductViewModel
        {
           CustomerID   = product.ID,
             CustomerFName = product.name,
             CustomerLName = product.lname,
             CustomerAge = product.age 

        });
    }
```

please some one help me put what i am doing wrong? i tried to pass my model on the page header

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Areas/aspx/Views/Shared/Web.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<CustomerTest.Models.ProductViewModel>>" %>
```

It worked fine but i have mutiple grids on my single page and they are coming from different tables so thats why i want to pass each model differently please someone help me in this code thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on your Printc method. You have to return a Json object create for the Kendo Grid :

```
public ActionResult Index_Printc([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    return Json(GetCustomers().ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

On my side, I specify the ID on the Ajax request, I don't know if it's mandatory for a read request, but if the update of the method doesn't work, add this :

```
<%: Html.Kendo().Grid<CustomerTest.Models.ProductViewModel>()
   .Name("grid")
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.CustomerID))
          .Read(read => read.Action("Printc", "Home") 
          )
      )
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(product => product.CustomerID);
          columns.Bound(product => product.CustomerFName);
          columns.Bound(product => product.CustomerLName);
      })
      .Pageable()
      .Sortable()
%>
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: one more thing how can i add a combo box in my grid column i want to make CustomerFName as my dropdown

Comment: Have a look on this example : http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom.html I may help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you have several grids on the same page make sure that they have unique names and not all of them are called grid.

Comment: this isn't an answer.  It should be a comment